# Can't install Google Chrome on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome

Google Chrome won't install on Vista.

I go to the official page, download the executable, run it. It opens a screen with a progress bar. That finishes and then nothing...

No maps are installed. I've used [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) to search for anything that might be related to "chrome" and/or "google", but no browser...

I'm out of ideas here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a link](http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/201.1/chrome_installer.exe) to the latest version on Chrome (Chrome 4, dev build 201.1); this is the **full** installer, not what you get from the official page (that's only a small executable that downloads the full installer). Maybe this will work for you. It's not exactly normal, it should install or at least give you an error.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I monitored it with Process Explorer. I double click the .exe, it appears in the programs list, opens a "setup.exe", but then the install.exe is killed and the setup.exe disappears too...

Comment: Have you tried checking if it got installed? There is no completion indicator for the installer (I have no idea why). It did the exact thing for me at work; I was monitoring the installer to see what was going on, but when I finally gave up, I noticed it had gotten installed. Just to be on the same side, check your profile to see if it's gotten installed (I think it's **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\**)

Comment: I have the Google folder, but no chrome folder. There's a folder named "1.2.183.7", which contains **GoogleCrashHandler.exe** and **goopdate.dll**. That's all there is.

Comment: I just now tried it on a virtual image of Windows7, it worked, no problems... Must be something I did in the past. I had it installed once, but uninstalled for some reason...

Comment: This will sound strange, but consider unmarking my answer as accepted because it did not solve your problem. Leave it open for a few more days, maybe someone will come up with a solution to your problem. I'd be happier if you actually got a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the installer go up to the top of the page where the little arrow is open it up.
2. Click open folder containing the download.
3. Right click on chrome go down to properties.
4. After clicking properties down at the bottom will be unblock click it then click apply at the bottom.

You are good to go reopen the installer from the previous folder and it should install.